# Htaccess Mod-Rewrite Not Rewriting

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

```
#Hide Index
IndexIgnore *

#Define ErrorDoc
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.domain.com

#REDIRECTS
Redirect 301 /page.php http://domain.com
Redirect 301 /inc/page.php http://domain.com


Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

#Redirect all pages in a folder to a single URL
RewriteRule ^dir/(.*)$ http://domain.com/index.php [L,R=301]

#Redirect String
RewriteRule ^index.php?var1=value&var2=(.*)&var3=(.*)$ http://domain.com [L,R=301]


#Rewrite www to domain 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

I'm using the above htaccess file to 301 redirect pages that have been removed from the server to the home page.

**Can anyone tell me why the line *#redirect string* does not rewrite to the home page?**

Answer (score 1):

It's likely due to the unescaped `?` in your match string.

Try `^index\.php\?var1=value&var2=[^&]*&var3=[^&]*$`.